# Invalid numeric literal when passing a truncated JSON object to jq

Tags: bash

I have a response from cURL which looks like this:

```
{"username": "bot", "verified": true, "locale": "en-US", "mfa_enabled": false, "bot": true, "id": "123", "flags": 0, "avatar": null, "discriminator": "3114", "email": null} 200
```

which is stored in variable called `auth`

Then I want to be able to loop that object doing this:

```
response=$(jq -c "." <<< "${auth::-3}")
```

Note that I remove the last 3 characters because those are the status code.

So technically it should work, but it returns: `parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 11`

If I enter the raw JSON as a string, it works. But not like this. Why?

Comment: I'd suggest `${auth% *}` instead; that way you're just removing everything after the last space, and not relying on version-dependent features (`${var::-3}` isn't supported in bash 3.x, which are still around today on systems like MacOS where they aren't willing to accept GPLv3 licensing).

Comment: BTW, you might consider `response=$(jq -n "${auth% *}")` instead, getting rid of the herestring usage -- that way enabling tracing with `set -x` will show you the exact string passed to `jq` (in shell-escaped form), allowing easier debugging / comparison to what you expect.

Comment: Splendid, that did the trick!

Comment: Good deal. I posted a slightly more paranoid version (which doesn't allow content that's jq code rather than JSON content to perform a denial-of-service attack) as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
response=$(jq -n --argjson auth "${auth% *}" '$auth')
```

...which will work correctly with versions of bash too old to correctly support `${auth::-3}` (a 4.x-only feature), and which will also log enough details to track down any issue caused by the content passed to `jq` when run with `bash -x yourscript`.